Wireless doorbell modification
I bought this cheap wireless doorbell on Aliexpress https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004524467677.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.106.6c021802keB7Mf
The button action a piezoelectric mechanism that feeds the board and send a signal to the chime.  I want to replace the piezoelectric module and instead feed the board with the raspberry pi ( 4 model B) so that i can simulate a button press programmatically and therefore ring the chime.
I soldered a black cable on the N point of the board and the red cable on the L point of the board. I have some electronic component at my disposition ( i used to study electronic back in my day but don't quite remember everything ) I would appreciate some guidance. I measured a peak of 0.4V at the board the piezoelectric button is pushed

EDIT : When pressing the doorbel button, it actions the element on the top of picture, it's a magnetic ( probably kinetic energy ? ) which is then connected to the board


how are you measuring the 0.4 V?

Your explanation is not quite clear to me. Some more details would help: 1) Is the piezoelectric device in the button enclosure that is pushed (i.e. outside the living area)? 2) Is the piezoelectric device connected by any wires to the chime that (presumably) is inside the living area? i.e. is this a wireless system? 3) Re the picture in your question: Is this a picture of the chime, the piezoelectric unit - or both?? Labels added to the picture would help.

@Seamus Yes the button is self powered and wireless, Once the button is pressed it sends a radio signal to the Chime plugged in on the AC ( which i am not touching ). I may have misunderstood how the button generates electricity to send the signal but i have updated my post

I am assuming that you want to connect the Raspberry Pi to the push button board so that the Raspberry Pi can remotely trigger the bell.
You should be able to do this by pulsing a GPIO line high and then low again. This would generate a pulse of 3.3 volts. I would use a voltage divider circuit to take the voltage down from 3.3 to .4 volts.

These values should give you around 0.42 volts for a 3.3 volt GPIO pin (Vout = (R2 / (R1 + R2)) * Vin).
I think that the duration of the pulse from the piezo xtal would be quite short, so something like a millisecond pulse should do the trick. If not, try timings either side of that, but I would not have thought that it would be critical.

The button closes a circuit, if this does not work well, try using a transistor instead.

@goldilocks I suspect that the button hits a piezo crystal (as Gaetan56 suggests) to generate a small amoount of electricity, which is used to generate a wireless or bluetooth signal that the other (powered) unit is watching for. The button unit is advertised as being battery-free - so it must be a piezo button, I think.

@goldilocks I think there are two parts: a powered ringer unit, and an unpowered button unit. The button hits the piezo crystal, which generates a small pulse of electricity. This is enough to power the transmitter circuit inside the button housing, which sends a pulse of RF to the powered ringer unit.

Yep, my bad again!  There I was thinking it was a bit daft to have a one piece doorbell that needs to be plugged in.  Blinders on.

@goldilocks - I do it all the time :)

A couple of thoughts: 1.) Piezoelectric devices generate high voltages; e.g. they are used to ignite gas stoves.  2.) The voltage divider you've employed: Its purpose is to divide down the 3.3V from a GPIO pin? Are you depending on a switch closure - or are you depending upon the piezoelectric crystal's output to signal the RPi?

@Seamus The OP has measured 0.4v, so I guess the piezo crystal is under a load (which it must be if it is going to do anything) - or is transformered down. The purpose of the divider is so that a Raspberry Pi can be used to simulate clicking on the piezo in the button unit (without the piezo crystal being involved at all). The button unit will then send a wireless signal to the bell sounder. So basically the Raspberry Pi can make the bell sound without being connected to it, and from a distance away.

Uh, no... no one would put a transformer on the output of a piezo-electric device. And the OP did not say how he measured the 0.4 volts (with a dc VM??). It's just my opinion, but I don't believe your answer will work.

@Seamus I am just assuming that the 0.4 v the OP measured was the voltage supplied to the wireless signal-generating circuit. I am assuming it was generated by the piezo crystal, and was processed in some way to result in a supply voltage of 0.4v.

Awfully big assumption IMHO.

@Seamus - you may be right - it would be good if the OP could clarify.

Yes the button is self powered and wireless, Once the button is pressed it sends a radio signal to the Chime plugged in on the AC ( which i am not touching ).
Unfortunately the solution is not working, i am still trying to understand why

Is the 0.4 volts that you measured, on the power rail to the circuitry inside the push button unit? If so can you simulate this by outputting a pulse from a GPIO pin on the Pi using the divider circuit I put up? Ideally a voltmeter should show the same 0.4v pulse when you press the piezo button as when you send an output pulse from the Pi.

@Lee-xp yes I did measure it with a voltmeter at the output of the power rail. I need recheck what I did

"Unfortunately the solution is not working" so WHY did you accept the Answer?

Apologies for the confusion, I reviewed my set up and it's working now, one resistor was KO but I changed the components
